# GetCallbackEventReference doesn't work synchronously

Tags: asp.net, callback, webforms, asp.net-3.5

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 WebForm that leverages the frameworks Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference() method and I'd like some of the calls to be synchronous.

Now, the documentation says that the 5th parameter (see below) controls this.  Specifically, when you pass 'false' it's supposed to be a non-asynchronous call.  However, regardless if it's true or false, it still processes the call asynchronously.

```
Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "ReceiveServerData", "context",false);
```

Is there a work-around for this or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**ASPX Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="How-to-use-GetCallbackEventReference.aspx.vb" Inherits="How_to_use_Callback" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>How to use GetCallbackEventReference</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetNumber() {
                UseCallback();
            }
            function GetRandomNumberFromServer(txtGetNumber, context) {
                document.forms[0].txtGetNumber.value = txtGetNumber
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Get Random Number" onclick="GetNumber()" /><br /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGetNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Partial Class How_to_use_Callback
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler
    Dim CallbackResult As String = Nothing
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim cbReference As String = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(Me, "arg", "GetRandomNumberFromServer", "context")
        Dim cbScript As String = "function UseCallback(arg,context)" & "{" & cbReference & " ; " & "}"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "UseCallback", cbScript, True)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCallbackResult() As String Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult
        Return CallbackResult
    End Function

    Public Sub RaiseCallbackEvent(ByVal eventArgument As String) Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent
        CallbackResult = Rnd().ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

For any other poor souls still using the MS AJAX library I found the following post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4134c2e-ca04-423a-9da3-c613713a7b52/synchronous-callbacks-with-the-net-20-framework?forum=netfxjscript

The last comment from an MS source says:

> This is actually by design. In order not to block the UI of the browser, this parameter doesn't actually do the request synchronously but makes sure the requests are queued and only one is going on at any given time. The effect is pretty much the same, except that the end-user can still use the browser UI while the request is going on and he won't have to kill the process if the server fails to respond or the network connection falls.

The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153103.aspx) confirms this:

> When sending data synchronously in a callback scenario, synchronous callbacks return immediately and do not block the browser. No two synchronous callbacks callback can execute at the same time in the browser. If a second synchronous callback is fired while one is currently pending, the second synchronous callback cancels the first and only the second callback will return.